# How to find the amount of work done against gravity from an object moving diagonally?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, work

[image: Particles moving in different directions.]

Particle 1 has a mass of 0.102 kg. It is carried from Point A at (0,0) to Point B at (3,0) and then from Point B to point C at (3,4). Particle 2 also has a mass of 0.102 kg. It is carried directly from A to C. Gravity acts in the −z direction as shown.

How much work is done against gravity in moving Particle 1 from A to C?

I wasn't sure how to do this, but I assumed even though the magnitude of the vector from A to C was five, the height was still 4, thus I used the W = mgh formula and substituted h for 4. What I want to know is if my work below is correct, but since the particle is moving diagonally, I don't know if just taking the height is sufficient.

To find the amount of work done against gravity ($9.8 \mathrm{m/s^2}$), we use the formula:

Work Against Gravity = Mass * Acceleration Due to Gravity * Height, $W = mgh$

mass, $m= 0.102\mathrm{kg}$

acceleration due to gravity, $g = 9.8 \mathrm{m/s^2}$

height, $h= 4 \mathrm{m}$

Thus, $W = 0.102 \mathrm{kg}\cdot 9.8 \mathrm{m/s^2}\cdot4 \mathrm{m}$
$W = 4  \mathrm{Joules}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your answer is correct. 
More generally: the work done by gravity (even more generally: by a "conservative field") is independant of the path.

Or, to answer your objection that the length is larger then the height: yes, that's right, but the force *in the moving direction* is less by the same factor. The projection of the weight on the direction of movement is $\frac 45 mg $. Any way of thinking gives the same result.